# Prevent scroll/jump when clicking anchor

Tags: scroll, onclick, anchor

I am using an image gallery/slider with css and because of the id's the page jumps down to where the images are located. 
Ex.    http://www.respasalon.com/blog-test.php

```
<div id="image-slider">
<div id="slide-frame">
<img src="img/reverseclock.jpg" alt="" />
<div id="slides">
  <img id="slide1" src="img/reverseclock.jpg" alt="" />
  <img id="slide2" src="img/reverseclock2.jpg" alt="" />
  <img id="slide3" src="img/reverseclock3.jpg" alt="" />

</div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<a href="#slide1">1</a>
<a href="#slide2">2</a>
<a href="#slide3">3</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   $('#navigation a').click(function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var contentId = $(this).attr('href');
      var content = $(document).find(contentId);
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(content).offset().top},
  'slow');
}):
```

This will smoothly scroll to div mention in href.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to stop it completely?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   $('#navigation a').click(function (evt) {
      // Put your logic here
      evt.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and it prevents my links from working. The links I'm using are on images (slide show, with 1 - 2 - 3 linked below the photo to go through each picture). When I put this script in the pictures don't change when you click on the link.

Comment: You have to put that image slide show logic inside the javascript function where I put the comment "Put You Logic here", There are so many methods to do that e.g. simple make them display block or hide based on what url is click, like in your case every single anchar has a specific href slide1 and that is also the id of img which is supposed to be displayed. simple hide all the images and then display only the one which is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't know what you meant by logic - not sure what is the logic.